# How to Display Pseudocode with New Commands

Tags: algorithmicx, pseudocode

I want to write pseudocode in TeXShop, with my own commands. The only commands I need to have are save, repeat, return, and if/elif/else. Can someone please help me with that? I was trying to figure it out by using the `algorithmicx` package to define the new commands, but I kept getting errors. (I don't actually care which package I use as long as it outputs the correct code.)

Here's the pseudocode I want it to display:

```
save count = 0
save i = 0
repeat len(L)
    if compare(e, L[i]) == 0
        count += i
    i += 1
return count
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include (print) Latex source code in generated pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156585/how-to-include-print-latex-source-code-in-generated-pdf) or [Write pseudo code in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768) or [LaTeX/Algorithms (wikibooks)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms)

Comment: Hi, I linked a related question. To me, your question is not very clear; regarding the goal and the problem :).

Comment: Related packages are `minted`, `listings`, `algorithm`, `algorithmic`, `algorithm2e`, `algorithmicx`, `program`, https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms, see https://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode. (**Disclaimer:** I commented this in a hurry so there is a non-zero chance that I missed something or that I made a mistake :))